# How to get realtime database object filtered by param?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image: DB structure screenshot]

```
    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.child("words");

    Query word = ref.orderByChild("lang1").equalTo("home");
    word.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Word w = singleSnapshot.getValue(Word.class);
                Log.i(String.valueOf(R.string.app_name), new Gson().toJson(w));
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
```

Could you tell me what am I doing wrong? Here I am, trying to get some "Words" from DB & send Json to Console...

UPD: Imported JSON file

```
{
    "words" : {
        "1" : {
            "id" : 1,
            "lang1" : "s1",
            "lang2" : "d1",
            "type" : "a"
        } , 
        "2" : {
            "id" : 2,
            "lang1" : "s2",
            "lang2" : "d2",
            "type" : "a"
        } // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: In the screenshot you shared, there is no child node under `words` with a property `rus`. It'll be easier to help if you share the JSON that you're querying as text, instead of a screenshot. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Are you going to use that order always? or not much?