# What is construction of Json DB for Android Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I uploaded such json to firebase console of realtime database. And to get some "words" im trying get child "words" with orderByChild ... startAt and so on...
Someone on this forum told me [there is no any child in "words"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45819968/how-to-get-realtime-database-object-filtered-by-param#comment78600255_45819968). Whats wrong?

```
{
"words" : {
    "1" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "lang1" : "s1",
        "lang2" : "d1",
        "type" : "a"
    } , 
    "2" : {
        "id" : 2,
        "lang1" : "s2",
        "lang2" : "d2",
        "type" : "a"
    } // ...
  }
}
```

And my Java code:

```
Query fb = FirebaseDatabase
            .getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("words")
            .orderByChild("lang1")
            .startAt("s2")
            .limitToFirst(20);
```

BTW. I can not get any responce. This listener does not return anything.

```
fb.add... ValueEventListener() {
        ... void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Word w = singleSnapshot.getValue(Word.class);
                Log.i(TAG, new Gson().toJson(w));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you get in response?

Comment: I can not get any responce. This listener does not return anything.
    fb.add... ValueEventListener() {
            ... void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Word w = singleSnapshot.getValue(Word.class);
                    Log.i(TAG, new Gson().toJson(w));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });

Comment: Check if you get any response by removing the orderByChild() and startAt() methods.